# Terminal freezes after "exit" command in bash script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I'm running Terminal Version 2.6.1 on Mac.
I'm writing a bash script, and I want to exit the script if a certain condition is met.

I do that with this command:

```
exit 1
```

after doing that, the script exits and I see this on the terminal:

```
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

After that, my terminal is frozen and I can't do anything with it anymore.

Is there a way to negate having to open up a new terminal each time the script quits?

---

I am running the script from my terminal like this:

```
. script.sh
```

Comment: Huh. My MacOS system doesn't have a `quit` command at all. I'd be curious as to what `type quit` returns for you. (As the existing answer says, the proper way to cause the shell running a script to quit is `exit`).

Comment: BTW, how are you running your script? If you do it with `. yourscript` or `source yourscript`, then the script is being run by your main interpreter, so exiting it exits the terminal.

Comment: Whooops! Yup I meant exit but I wrote quit

Comment: `exec yourscript` will similarly replace your interactive shell with the one running the script, so when the script exits you have nothing left.

Comment: ...so you really do need to specify not just what's in your script, but how you're actually running it for this question to be answerable.

Comment: The terminal isn't freezing. You exited the shell process that you were running in the terminal.

Comment: ...btw, it's tricky to figure out how to deal with this case re: StackOverflow norms -- *normally*, after an answer exists, changing a question in a way that invalidates that answer is frowned on, and the right practice is to ask a new/different question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If it's a correction to a mistake in the question, it's OK to edit. The answers can be deleted or edited if they no longer apply.

Comment: The question is *why* are you running the script as `. script.sh`?  There are reasons to do that, but it's atypical, and is generally the wrong thing to do.

Comment: This post really answered my question quite well:
http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip

Answer (score 4):

Don't use

```
. script.sh
```

to run the script. This runs the script in the same interactive shell that you're using in the Terminal session, and when the script uses `exit`, that exits the interactive shell as well.

Start the script with this line, which tells the OS to use `bash` to execute the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Give it execute permission with:

```
chmod 755 script.sh
```

and then run it with

```
./script.sh
```

This runs the script in its own process.

Comment: `. script.sh` is one way this could happen (like its synonym `source script.sh`); `exec ./script.sh` is another.

Comment: That's why I didn't recommend that. He should just do what I said in the answer.

Comment: Sorry? I was offering a second/alternate theory of what the mistake could be, not a second proposed fix.

Comment: @Barmar what about "bash script.sh"? This seems to negate the need to set permissions.

Comment: @etayluz, if you do that, someone has to know which interpreter your script needs to be run with before they can use the script. That also means that if you rewrite the script to be written in a different language, every single other script that calls/uses it needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @etayluz, moreover, that means the `.sh` name is actively misleading (inasmuch as it implies POSIX sh compatibility, thus that `sh yourscript` would work). In general, executable files define commands, and command names don't have extensions (you don't run `ls.elf`). This is true for other languages as well -- Python *modules* have `.py` extensions, for instance, but Python *commands* (ie. entry points created by `python setup.py install` and similar) don't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Some people like the convention of using `.sh` for any shell dialect. While it's not needed for running the script, it's useful when listing the directory to know that it's a script rather than a binary executable.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, some people like it, but at least in freenode #bash there's an established agreement that it's a Bad Idea nonetheless (see http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh for factoid history on the subject).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy They have their opinion, I have mine.

Comment: @Barmar, ...do you have a refutation for any of the arguments I made in stating my own opinion on the topic above? (If you don't want to engage, I'm happy to go do other things, but I'm also curious).

Comment: ...if we're going to get into this, btw, let me clarify my position: `.sh` is actually *useful* in a context where a script is intended to be sourceable by any POSIX sh interpreter (likewise `.bash` for something intended to be sourced into a preexisting bash interpreter, `.ksh`, etc). It's strictly in cases where a script is only intended to be executed and not sourced where I'm somewhat stridently against.

Comment: I gave my reason. When I'm listing a directory full of executables, it's helpful to know that a script is a standalone text file that I can edit, rather than a binary for which I need to find the source code.

Comment: Ahh. I have vim filters that run `objdump` on an ELF file, so opening one up in an editor is actually useful. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what is the difference between sourcing and executing a script?

Comment: @etayluz sourcing a script runs it in the same shell process, executing the script starts a child process to run it.

Comment: This explains it well: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip